# Javascript specific to Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have lots of rails and javascript code in one project. So far it works fine, but on one particular place Javascript is not working in Chrome, works in other browsers.

The form itself has a checkbox. Once it is selected it will enable textboxes on the form. On initial load, it is not enabling the fields. But as soon as I select "inspect elements" in Chrome, and close inspect elements window it starts working, javascript kicks in and works as it should.

There is so much code behind, that it would be really difficult to post it here. I am hoping there is some "magic" only specific to Chrome.

Did anyone ever had this kind of problem before?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to determine what "magic" might be causing your issue.

Comment: Setup a minimal [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your issue.

Comment: hey i had same issue but it was with jQuery masonry and i added `setTimeout()` and it started working ;) Now, we haven't seen your code so, it is hard to guess that this trick will also work for you.

Comment: @AspiringAqib... very strange, we also use Masonry in our project, but this is the backend, and there are no Masonry JS libraries loaded. However, I do not believe in coincidences, would you be kind enough to explain me how did you use setTimeout()?

Comment: I have installed web developer for Chrome. Strange thing, as soon as I select ANY options within the Addon, JS starts working. Seems like I trigger some sort of refresh or something...

Comment: Is it something that was working earlier but has now broken? If so, you could try using your source control's bisect command to find the revision where it started to go wrong.

Comment: This is new feature. It works on Opera and FF. While Safari and Chrome behave in identical way. All of the variables are checked, there are no loose ends. All logic is triple checked. And yet, same strange behavior. If I save the page as html (save as complete html) using Chrome, and I open that html it works

Comment: I got it on jsfiddle and it works there. I will post jsfiddle as soon as I strip the project related code